# Android/Java. Как cделать группировку сообщений usera в диалоге чата?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, xmpp, chat

Есть вкладка Диалоги.. В ней ListView.. В ListView с помощью кастомного симпладаптера вставляется View с двумя TextEdit..
Первому TextEdit присваивается Имя usera от которого пришло msg
Второму TextEdit присв собственно само msg

Все работает норм.. Но когда от usera приходит новое msg оно добавляется снова! И происходит дублирование! типа:

user1
msg1
user1
msg2
user1
msg3

Как сгруппировать эти сообщения?? Помогите написать код такой что Нужно как бы проверить что если имя user1 уже есть в массиве, значит msg1 заменить последним пришедшим msg..

У меня код такой:

```
public static class MydialogsAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

       private List<HashMap<String, String>> results;
       private Context mContext;

       public MydialogsAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) 
        {

            super(context, data, resource, from, to);
            this.results = data;
            this.mContext = context;
}
         public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
         {

            View v = view;

            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_dialogs, null);
            }

            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_msg);
            TextView cur = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cur);

            String tmp = (String) tt.getText().toString();

            if (results.get(position).get("from").equals(results.get(results.size()-1).get("from"))) 
            {           

            tt.setText(results.get(results.size()-1).get("from"));  
            cur.setText(results.get(results.size()-1).get("body"));

         return v;

          }
            else
            {

            tt.setText(results.get(position).get("from"));
            cur.setText(results.get(position).get("body"));

           /* if ((position == results.size()-1)&&(position != 0))
                  results.remove(results.get(position));*/

            return v;
            }
      }
    }}
```

Я сравниваю вроде, но все равно дублируется.. Никак разобраться не могу с этим..

Comment: Вам надо добавить реализацию `ViewHolder` в адаптер

Comment: И как это поможет?.. я просто не понимаю.. А можно как то мой код переписать этот в методе getView?

Comment: Помочь может переиспользованием элементов разметки в методе `getView`. Переписать код ваш можно, но как - не помню, ибо давно не использую устаревший `ListView`. Посмотрите в сети - там полно примеров.

Comment: Можешь скрин приложить, как это выглядит, а то не очень понятно как они дублируются? Приходит новое сообщение и сразу выводиться все старые сообщения вместе?